# Chat Redis+node.js

Tags: архитектура, redis, проектирование, mysql

Вся текущая сеансовая переписка пользователей хранится в Redis. Сейчас в планах сохранять всю историю переписки и выводить последние записи в диалоге сообщений. Опять же читать с redis? Если да, то как хранить данные диалогов, или же тянуть с redis после завершения диалога и ложить в Mysql?

Answer (score 2):

Если уже сейчас хватает NoSQL решения то зачем подключать SQL? Разве вам необходимы какие то сложные выборки или объединения таблиц?

Comment: Да - но Redis насколько я помню - очищается. да и если перезагружать сервер - данные теряются.

Comment: чепуха, у редиса есть полноценный файл базы, в котором все прекрасно хранится. по завершении сесси перемещайте чат в ключ-хэш, я использую название вида archive:user_id:date, при необходимости прекрасно все достается